# Vue JS 3 - Custom Radio Button is unchecked the first time it renders

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, frameworks, vue-component

I'm trying to create a custom radio component in vue js 3, according to the official documentation it can be done using v-model. I tried to apply it, but the first time the component is rendered it doesn't check the selected value but the value can be updated when I try to select another value.

my code is like the following:

## App.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    {{ picked }}
  </div>
  <RadioButton value="One" v-model="picked" />
  <RadioButton value="Two" v-model="picked" />
</template>

<script>
import RadioButton from "./components/RadioButton.vue";

export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    RadioButton,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      picked: "One",
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

## RadioButton.vue

```
<template>
  <input
    type="radio"
    name="group"
    :value="modelValue"
    @input="$emit('update:modelValue', $event.target.value)"
  />
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "RadioButton",
  props: ["modelValue"],
  emits: ["update:modelValue"],
};
</script>
```

I have simulated my code here. https://codesandbox.io/s/restless-cache-2svtiz?file=/src/components/RadioButton.vue you can see it. Thank You

Answer (score 6):

Here is a working example for Vue3 with composition.

**App.vue**

```
<div>
  <label for="one">One</label>
  <RadioButton
    id="one"
    v-model="picked"
    name="num"
    value="One"
  />
  <br>
  <label for="two">Two</label>
  <RadioButton
    id="two"
    v-model="picked"
    name="num"
    value="Two"
  />
  <br>
  Picked value: {{ picked }}
</div>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref } from 'vue'

const picked = ref('One');
</script>
```

**RadioButton.vue**

```
<template>
  <input
    type="radio"
    :value="value"
    :checked="isChecked"
    @change="$emit('update:modelValue', $event.target.value)"
  >
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { computed, defineProps } from 'vue';

const props = withDefaults(
  defineProps<{
    value?: string
    modelValue?: string
  }>(),
  {
    value: undefined,
    modelValue: '',
  },
);

defineEmits(['update:modelValue']);

const isChecked = computed(() => {
  return props.modelValue === props.value;
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In RadioButton.vue, add one props again, like this:

```
props: {
modelValue: String,
checked: {
  type: Boolean,
  required: false,
  default: false,
}
```

Dont forget to add `:checked="checked"` in the input component.
And finally, in the App.vue, add `:checked="true"` to the custom component that you want to make checked by default.